# Why is my 100% height waaay oversized?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to track down why my background containers "background-overlay" and "background-gradient" are pushing the height of the document well beyond the content displayed? I'm not sure what's going on here. Probably something too simple.

Here is the template in work http://jordan.rave5.com/tmp/

I'm not sure what the code problem is I think something to do with the two aforementioned classes.

**Possible culprits:**

```
            #background-overlay {
                z-index: 100;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                background-color: #273722;
                background-image: url(images/main-bg.png);
                background-repeat: repeat;
                background-attachment: fixed;
                opacity: 0.0;
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
            }

            #background-gradient {
                position: fixed;
                z-index: 200;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                background-image: url(images/main-grad.png);
                background-repeat: repeat-x;
                background-position: top;
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                overflow: auto;
            }
```

**HTML**

```
    <div id="background-overlay">
        <div id="background-gradient">

            <div id="header-image-grad">

                    <div id="header">
                        <div id="header-container">
                            <div id="navigation-container">
                                <div id="navigation">
                                    <span id="nav">Navigation Area...</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                <div id="header-image-border">
                    <img class="header-img" src="slides/fields.jpg" alt="Panoramic Fields" />
                    <div class="image-grad"></div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div id="body">
                <div id="body-content"></div>
                <div class="loading"><img src="images/loading.gif" alt="Loading Content" /></div>
            </div>

            <div id="footer">
                <br />
                <div id="footer-content">
                    Footer Area...
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Remove** `margin-top:100%` in your `#footer-content id`

Comment: Thanks man... Now I just gotta figure out how to get that footer to stay on the bottom.

Comment: @WASasquatch Now used to sticky footer http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/   ----------  http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: I think I got it setting gradient to relative and the footer to absolute bottom.

Answer (score 0):

because your `background-image:` on your background-gradient id is has 2000px as its height

Answer (score 0):

Your footer has its margin set to 100%